# Find the direction of one rectangle relative to other

Tags: c#, geometry, coordinates, rectangles

**Problem**
How can i find the direction of one rectangle w.r.t to the other. The directions i am interested is up, down, left, and right. My rectangle is represented by a Cell class. I am trying to write a function in that cell class. Function accepts a parameter of Cell type the returns the direction either 1(up) 2(down) 3(left), or 4(right) of the passed cell w.r.t to the calling cell.

**What i tried**
I found the mid point of both the rectangles, and then compared the x, and y coordinates. But this technique is not working in all the cases. whenever i find a missing case, i have to include more and more if statements which i think is not a good programming practice. its becoming more and more error prone and difficult to understand.

**While searching for the solution:** maybe math.atan2() can work in my case. Maybe i can find the angle between mid points of these 2 rectangles and use the value of angle to determine the direction. But i am not sure if my thinking is correct.

**Please guide me.** Should i keep using my function and rectify it, or is there a better solution such as math.atan2()? A helping image for better understanding and a required solution is demonstrated below after the code.

**Code**

```
public int dirOfThisCell(Cell cell)
    {
        int dir = 0;

        //find mid points of both cells
        PointF midPointThis = this.computeAndGetMidPoint();
        PointF midPointCell = cell.computeAndGetMidPoint();
        //MessageBox.Show(mess);
        //if x of both points is same or with little variance because of variance in sizes of cells
        ===>>  //Comparison Starts!!
        if (midPointThis.X > midPointCell.X)
        {
            //this cell is to the right.
            if ((midPointCell.Y) == (midPointThis.Y))
            {
                 dir = 3;
            }
            else if (Math.Abs(midPointCell.Y) - Math.Abs(midPointThis.Y) < 5) { dir = 3; }
            else if (Math.Abs(midPointCell.Y) - Math.Abs(midPointThis.Y) > 5) {
                if (midPointThis.Y > midPointCell.Y) { dir = 1; }
                else if (midPointThis.Y < midPointCell.Y) dir = 2;
            }
                // a considerable difference

            else { dir = 3; }

                //some small variations in y
            //else if(Math.Abs()
        }

        else if (midPointThis.X < midPointCell.X)
        {
             // this cell is to the left
            if ((midPointCell.Y) == (midPointThis.Y))
            {
                dir = 4;
            }
            else if (Math.Abs(midPointCell.Y) - Math.Abs(midPointThis.Y) <= 10)
            {
                dir = 4;
            }
        }

        //if this cell is below 
        else if (midPointThis.Y > midPointCell.Y)
        {
            //this cell is down than the cell
            if ((midPointCell.X) == (midPointThis.X))
            {
                dir = 1;
            }
            //else if (Math.Abs(midPointCell.X) - Math.Abs(midPointThis.X) < 2) { dir = 1; }
        }

        else if (midPointThis.Y < midPointCell.Y)
        {
            if ((midPointCell.X) == (midPointThis.X))
            {
                dir = 2;
            }
        }
        return dir;
    }
```

**Image**

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRySH.png)

Sample rectangles are shown in the picture number wise. The rectangle can be of single cell or made by combining multiple numbered cells.

**Sample Solution required**

1. Direction of cell 18 w.r.t to 8 should be up(1)
2. Direction of cell 18 w.r.t to 10 should be up(1)
3. Direction of cell 14 w.r.t to 13 should be right(4)
4. Direction of cell 9 w.r.t to 31 should be down(1)
5. Direction of cell 15 w.r.t to 9 should be left(3)

I am working in c#.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: I don't understand how using Math.Abs is helping you. A cell will have a negative value for X if it to the left, and for Y if it is below the current cell. By removing the negative, you are just converting displacement (which includes direction, which is what you want) to distance (which is what you don't want).

Comment: Not to mention, you are using an int to hold a direction which by definition has 2 values. If a cell is up, that doesn't mean that it is not also left. A cell can be both left and up. Consider using a struct with a horizontal direction (horDir) and vertical direction (verDir).

Comment: My advice: spend more time designing before writing code. Work out precisely when you want to choose up or down vs. left or right. You might even make a drawing of a sample grid on paper, then draw lines between your cells. If the lines go from cell centroid to centroid, good.  Your sort of directionality scheme has a name in the literature: "manhattan". By the way, the result you show in the second example shown in your Sample Solution appears to be incorrect. Cell 18 is substantially further east from Cell 10 than it is north. Is not the answer "right" rather than "up"?

Comment: If it truly is one direction that you are looking for. Once you have the values of both horizontal and vertical displacement. Convert these to absolute values and then whichever is larger, for example if X is larger than Y, then use the corresponding direction of X as your final result.

Comment: @O.Jones 

no, the answer should be "up". Reason. i am finding directions of adjacent cells. consider that 10, 9, and 8 form a rectangle then 18 is the adjacent cell whose direction should be up.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the angle of the center of a rectangle compared to the center of another does not seem to be a very good idea, because the center of those rectangles are only telling you where their center is and the solution is completely reluctant to the width, height and direction of the sides. I know that the third one is not a concern in your specific case as you can safely assume that the sides are horizontal XOR vertical, but in general terms, that could be an issue as well. To calculate the relative position of Shape1 (which is a rectangle in our particular case) compared to Shape2, you need to calculate the minimum and maximum x and y for both.

**Shape1 is to the left of Shape2 <=> Shape1.maxX <= Shape2.minX**

**Shape1 is to the right of Shape2 <=> Shape2.minX >= Shape2.maxX**

**Shape1 is above Shape2 <=> Shape1.maxY <= Shape2.minY**

**Shape2 is below Shape2 <=> Shape2.minY >= Shape1.maxY**

Comment: suppose i have a rectangle made up of cells 17, 18, 9, and 8. and i want to calculate the relative position of cell 20 .
Considering your first point :Shape1 is to the left of Shape2 <=> Shape1.maxX <= Shape2.minX

this results in output 'Left', but actually, the output should be 'Up'

There are more cases like that. What do you propose in this case and similar cases?

Comment: Can you tell me the coordinates of the boundaries of the two rectangles?